# How to filter a Sharepoint List Column with a Textbox Control Value using a "Contains" query?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, filter, textbox, contains

I'm using a data view to display a list (Sharepoint 2010) that has several columns including one that has a Name column. I've provided the user with a text filter on the page to send values to filter the Name column in this list. The problem I'm facing is that the filter only works for exact matches and not partial matches.

I tried to overcome this problem by using Sharepoint Designer to:

1. create a parameter that uses the textbox control value.
2. Filtering the Name column with this parameter and setting the comparison to "Contains"

Unfortunately if the default value of the Parameter is blank, the list does not display any data. If the default value of the parameter is set to part of a name in the list, the list displays names that contain that string. However, when changing the value in the text box and searching, the list does not return results. Please let me know if you guys know how to fix this. Any help is much appreciated and let me know if you need any additional information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find a solution to my problem. I used a custom javascript solution designed by jvossers ([http://instantlistfilter.codeplex.com](http://instantlistfilter.codeplex.com/)) that involves the list being filtered instantly much like Google's search!

The only downside of this solution is that it only filters the items currently displayed on the screen. Therefore, if you have a data view web part which limits the amount of items displayed on the page, this solution won't help you. In order to facilitate this solution, display all the row items on the page (by increasing the item limit per page to a larger number than your total list rows) and then add this code into a content editor web part on the same page. Worked brilliantly for me. '

By the way if you are using jQuery 1.3.x or higher, you should modify the script a little as described in the disscussion here: http://instantlistfilter.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=49123